# Set default values in dictionaries when not existent

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionaries for which I want to assign a value to a key if that key doesn't exist. I found myself writing this pretty often:

```
class Document(object):
    def __init__(properties):
        self.properties = properties
        self.properties['created']=properties.get('created',datetime.datetime.now())
        self.properties['foo']=properties.get('foo','bar')
```

Someone suggested this equivalent:

```
        self.properties = {'created',datetime.datetime.now(),'foo':'bar'}
        self.properties.update(properties)
```

Is there any benefit from using one or the other?
I was hoping to achieve this assignment in one line but unfortunately the `update()` method does not return the modified dictionary. Is there a good performant one-liner alternative?

Comment: This is just a toy example, there may be other properties and that's why the second version would be a kind of improvement over the first one in terms of readability and I could get that dictionary from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to use Python 3.5, [additional unpacking generalizations](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) makes this easy:

```
class Document(object):
    def __init__(self, properties):
        self.properties = {'created': datetime.datetime.now(), **properties}
```

If the properties `dict` is guaranteed to only have string keys, you could also do the following in any version of Python:

```
        self.properties = dict({'created': datetime.datetime.now()}, **properties)
```

And while it's a little ugly, for any version of Python, you can get a similar effect to the additional unpacking generalizations with:

```
from itertools import chain

...
        self.properties = dict(chain({'created': datetime.datetime.now()}.items(), properties.items()))
```

Lastly, if none of those are an option, you can at least avoid separate `get` and store operations, by using `setdefault`:

```
        self.properties = properties
        properties.setdefault('created', datetime.datetime.now())
```

`setdefault` acts like `get`, except it also stores the default value if there is no existing key. Note that like the `get` based version, this keeps the exact `dict` provided by the caller, mutating it, and remaining subject to being mutated by the caller in the future. All the other solutions avoid this. To fix that for either `get` or `setdefault`, change to:

```
        self.properties = properties.copy()
        self.properties.setdefault('created', datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: I'm in 2.7 but your second example is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `defaultdict` from the collections module:

```
from collections import defaultdict
>>> d=defaultdict(datetime.datetime.now)
>>> d['created']
datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 4, 16, 44, 42, 767328)
```

You could also use `setdefault`, a `dict` method:

```
class Document(object):
    def __init__(self,properties):
        self.properties = properties
        self.properties.setdefault('created',datetime.datetime.now())
```

Using `setdefault` won't set the other dict values to `datetime.datetime.now()`, so it is likely more appropriate for you.

Comment: `d=defaultdict( datetime.datetime.now)`, no need for an ugly lambda

Comment: It needs to be callable so you remove the parens.

Comment: I see your point, not all the properties will be of the same kind. Let me edit the question.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a case for a defaultdict. It sounds like for the *specific key* `'created'`, if that key isn't present, `datetime.datetime.now` should be called immediately and the value used for that entry. It doesn't sound like other missing entries should initialize themselves to the time of first access.

Comment: Downside is that's it's rather focused on solving one problem while potentially creating others. I somehow doubt all the properties should default to the current time; many of them probably aren't even supposed to be `datetime`s at all, and `defaultdict` always risks auto-vivifying keys due to simple typos.

Comment: Your second suggestion does work for my problem but in my case, the single line unpacker works better since in a real scenario I am reading the properties from somewhere else and instead of having to iterate and setting them I can do it in a one-liner. Thanks!